# Meta analysis in R with changes from baseline scores: SMD interpretation and sample size selection

Tags: r, meta-analysis, pre-post-comparison

I have two questions regarding a meta-analysis I am currently running.

**1. SMD interpretation for change from baseline scores**

In this meta-analysis, I have change from baseline scores and I am comparing RCTs psychosocial interventions vs control. Let's say I am comparing the change from baseline scores from an agitation questionnaire where higher scores means more agitation, how do I interpret the SMD I get?

I know that if I were to use post measures only and lower scores meant improvements, if the SMD was positive, it would favor control, and if the SMD was negative, it would favor the intervention.

But I am struggling to make sense of the interpretation for changes from baseline?

**2. Which sample size to input in the R analysis between baseline and post measurements?**

As I am using change from baseline scores, I have two sets of sample sizes for each of the intervention and control groups: one for baseline measures, and on for post measures, which are almost often different because of drops out. I have been looking for guidelines on which sample size to use, but had no luck.

Do you know of any best practice for this issue? Should I use baseline sample sizes or post measures sample sizes?

Thank you for your help!